# Stabilized propensity weights: intuition and ATT formula

Tags: propensity-scores, treatment-effect, weights

The average treatment effect (ATE) of binary treatment T on outcome Y can be estimated using inverse propensity weights:

\begin{equation}\nonumber
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}t_i\hat{\pi}_i^{-1}y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}t_i\hat{\pi}_i^{-1}}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1-t_i)(1-\hat{\pi}_i)^{-1}y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1-t_i)(1-\hat{\pi}_i)^{-1}} \xrightarrow{p} E[Y^1]-E[Y^0]
\end{equation}

where $\hat{\pi}_i$ is the estimated propensity for individual $i$, $Y^1$ is the outcome under treatment and $Y^0$ the outcome under the control condition.

To avoid extreme weights, there is a literature that suggests replacing the numerator of the treated weights with the marginal probability of treatment, $p(t=1)$, and the numerator of the control weights with $1-p(t=1)$. I see how this makes the weights milder, but **why those particular numerators? What is the intution of this stabilization?**

Also, the average treatment effect on the treated (ATT) can be estimated by weighting control units with the odds:

\begin{equation}\nonumber
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}t_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}t_i}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1-t_i)\hat{\pi}_i(1-\hat{\pi}_i)^{-1}y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1-t_i)\hat{\pi}_i(1-\hat{\pi}_i)^{-1}} \xrightarrow{p} E[Y^1|T=1]-E[Y^0|T=1]
\end{equation}

**How should one stabilize these** $\hat{\pi}_i(1-\hat{\pi}_i)^{-1}$ **weights?**